# C++ unpack variadic template parameters and call another template method

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to unpack variadic template parameters, and call "read<>" on each of them. And then collect the results of "read<>" to create a new tuple object.

This is what I wrote after learning "fold expression" in C++17:

```cpp
    template<typename ...U>
    std::tuple<U...> read_impl(std::tuple<U...>* arg) {
        // The argument exists for function overloading. As an alternative of partial specialization.
        using T = std::tuple<U...>;
        return T(read<U>(), ...);
    }
```

And I got [Fatal Error C1001 INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1001?view=msvc-170).

Intended usage:

```cpp
std::tuple<int, float, double> tup = read_impl(static_cast<std::tuple<int, float, double>*>(0));
// which is equivalent to
std::tuple<int, float, double> tup = std::make_tuple(read<int>(), read<float>(), read<double>());
```

And this is what I am currently doing, which is ugly and verbose without unpacking magic.

```cpp
    template<typename U1>
    std::tuple<U1> read_impl(std::tuple<U1>* arg) {
        using T = std::remove_pointer<decltype(arg)>::type;
        return T(read<U1>());
    }
    template<typename U1, typename U2>
    std::tuple<U1, U2> read_impl(std::tuple<U1, U2>* arg) {
        using T = std::remove_pointer<decltype(arg)>::type;
        return T(read<U1>(), read<U2>());
    }
    template<typename U1, typename U2, typename U3>
    std::tuple<U1, U2, U3> read_impl(std::tuple<U1, U2, U3>* arg) {
        using T = std::remove_pointer<decltype(arg)>::type;
        return T(read<U1>(), read<U2>(), read<U3>());
    }
    ...
```

Here is a minimal reproducible case:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

class Reader {
public:
    template<typename T>
    T read() {
        return read_impl(static_cast<T*>(0));
    }
    int read_impl(int*) {
        return 1;
    }
    float read_impl(float*) {
        return 0.5f;
    }
    template<typename ...U>
    std::tuple<U...> read_impl(std::tuple<U...>* arg) {
        using T = std::tuple<U...>;
        return T(read<U>(), ...);
    }

    static void test() {
        Reader reader;
        auto result = reader.read<std::tuple<int, float>>();
        assert(std::get<0>(result) == 1);
        assert(std::get<1>(result) == 0.5f);
    }
};

int main() {
    Reader::test();
    return 0;
}
```

=== Reply to some comments/answers: ===

@kiner_shah Why a raw pointer to a tuple? And why aren't you using arg in your read_impl?

Because if I want to specialize the generic "f" function based on different return value, it will not compile.

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <assert.h>

class Reader {
public:
    template<typename T>
    T f() {
        throw std::exception();
    }

    template<>
    int f() {
        return 1;
    }

    template<>
    float f() {
        return 0.5f;
    }

    static void test_f() {
        Reader reader;
        auto result = reader.f<int>();
        assert(result == 1);
    }
};

int main() {
    Reader::test_f();
    return 0;
}
```

=======

@Ted Lyngmo Your minimal reproducible example does not compile using any compiler.

That's why I am asking this question. I want it to compile.

Here is a more complete example of Reader. It needs to be able to read complex types like this: `reader.read<std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::string>>>()`.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

class Reader {
public:
    template<typename T>
    T read() {
        return read_impl(static_cast<T*>(0));
    }

    template<typename T>
    T read_impl(T*) {
        T::deserialize(*this);
    }
    uint64_t read_impl(uint64_t*) {
        return 1; // this will not be a constant in the real situation.
    }
    uint32_t read_impl(uint32_t*) {
        return 1; // this will not be a constant in the real situation.
    }
    int read_impl(int*) {
        return 1; // this will not be a constant in the real situation.
    }
    float read_impl(float*) {
        return .5f; // this will not be a constant in the real situation.
    }
    bool read_impl(bool*) {
        return true; // this will not be a constant in the real situation.
    }
    std::string read_impl(std::string*) {
        return "readString"; // this will not be a constant in the real situation.
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> read_impl(std::vector<T>*) {
        size_t size = read<uint64_t>();
        std::vector<T> r;
        r.reserve(size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            r.push_back(read<T>());
        }
        return r;
    }
    template<typename TKey, typename TValue>
    std::unordered_map<TKey, TValue> read_impl(std::unordered_map<TKey, TValue>*) {
        size_t size = read<uint64_t>();
        std::unordered_map<TKey, TValue> r;
        r.reserve(size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TKey k = read<TKey>();
            TValue v = read<TValue>();
            r[k] = v;
        }
        return r;
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::unordered_set<T> read_impl(std::unordered_set<T>*) {
        size_t size = read<uint64_t>();
        std::unordered_set<T> r;
        r.reserve(size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            r.insert(read<T>());
        }
        return r;
    }
    template<typename ...U>
    std::tuple<U...> read_impl(std::tuple<U...>* arg) {
        using T = std::tuple<U...>;
        return T{ read<U>() ... };
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::optional<T> read_impl(std::optional<T>* t) {
        bool hasValue = read<bool>();
        std::optional<T> r;
        if (hasValue) {
            r = read<T>();
        }
        return r;
    }

    static void test() {
        Reader reader;
        auto result = reader.read<std::tuple<int, float>>();
        assert(std::get<0>(result) == 1);
        assert(std::get<1>(result) == 0.5f);
        auto result2 = reader.read<std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::string>>>();
        assert(result2[1] == std::vector<std::string>{"readString"});
    }
};

int main() {
    Reader::test();
    return 0;
}
```

=======

@HolyBlackCat and @Jarod42 Thanks so much for pointing out the evaluation order issue in the code.

Comment: Why a raw pointer to a tuple? And why aren't you using `arg` in your `read_impl`?

Comment: @kiner_shah Because partial specialization is not valid for function template. And overloading is a good walkaround.

Comment: What is signature of the `read` function?

Comment: @felixh, sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Notice that there are no evaluation order between function parameters, so `read<U1>` might happen before or after `read<U3>`

Comment: @felixh Your approach (use pointers to find the right overload) is most probably not viable, because this way the overloads must be declared before being used (e.g. from the other overloads), which means that in the general case you must declare everything the second time at the top (which is annoying, especially if they're spread over multiple files).

Comment: The comma isn't needed, it should be `T(read<U>()...)`. Or rather `T{read<U>()...}` to fix the eval order, mentioned by Jarod42.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat does `{}` initialisation alter evaluation order logic?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Yes. Braced lists are always evaluated left-to-right, while for function arguments the order is unspecified (right-to-left at least on some compilers).

Comment: Maybe you could think of a solution using `if constexpr` and not specializations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would drop the specializations and use `if constexpr`. You also do not need pointers to `tuple`s.

Example:

```cpp
class Reader {
public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr std::tuple<T> read() {
        // return different values depending on type:
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) return 1;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) return 0.5f;
        return {};
    }

    // an overload that requires at least 2 template parameters:
    template <typename T, typename U, typename... V>
    constexpr std::tuple<T, U, V...> read() {
        return std::tuple_cat(read<T>(), read<U>(), read<V>()...);
    }

    static void test() {
        Reader reader;
        constexpr auto result = reader.read<int, float>();
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(result),
                                     const std::tuple<int, float>>);
        static_assert(std::get<0>(result) == 1);
        static_assert(std::get<1>(result) == 0.5f);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s5n7Y38rM)

If you *really* want to keep the implementations for reading `int` and `float` separate instead of using `if constexpr`, you can:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    requires std::is_same_v<T, int>
    constexpr std::tuple<T> read() {
        return 1;
    }
    
    template <typename T>
    requires std::is_same_v<T, float>
    constexpr std::tuple<T> read() {
        return 0.5f;
    }
```

---

If you need to be able to `read` not only into `tuple`s, you could make it even more generic without the need for pointers to the types you want to read from.

```cpp
// type trait to check if a type is a tuple:
template <typename...> struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};
template <typename... T> struct is_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> : std::true_type {};
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_tuple_v = is_tuple<T>::value;

class Reader {
public:
    template <typename T>
    requires std::is_same_v<T, int>
    constexpr int read() { return 1; }

    template <typename T>
    requires std::is_same_v<T, float>
    constexpr float read() { return 0.5f; }

    // and it supports more complex types, like tuples:
    template <typename T>
    requires is_tuple_v<T>
    constexpr T read() {
        return [this]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> T {
            return {this->read<std::tuple_element_t<I, T>>()...};
        }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<T>>{});
    }

    static void test() {/* same as above */ }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5W8Pdx9db)

---

Adding support for `unordered_map`s would follow the same pattern as for `tuple`s:

```cpp
// type trait:
template <typename...> struct is_unordered_map : std::false_type {};
template<class Key, class T, class Hash, class KeyEqual, class Allocator>
struct is_unordered_map<std::unordered_map<Key,T,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>> :
    std::true_type {};
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_unordered_map_v = is_unordered_map<T>::value;

// ...
    template<typename T>
    requires is_unordered_map_v<T>
    T read() {
        using TKey = typename T::key_type;
        using TValue = typename T::mapped_type;
        std::size_t size = read<std::uint64_t>();
        T r;
        r.reserve(size);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TKey k = read<TKey>();
            TValue v = read<TValue>();
            r[k] = v;
            //or, if the first Key value read should be kept:
            //r.emplace(read<TKey>(), read<TValue>());
        }
        return r;
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qbovxWjz1) with `unordered_map`, `vector` and `string`.

Comment: Can you elaborate why using `requires std::is_same_v<T, X>` is better than template specialization?

Comment: Might be a silly question:  why do I want constexpr in the return type?

And I don't want `reader.read<int, float>()`, I specifically need `reader.read<std::tuple<int, float>>()` to work, because the Reader class calls different "read" function recursively.

Comment: @sklott You mean like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xa5bTvc4s)? Nothing really, except gcc doesn't like the specialization.

Comment: @felixh I added `constexpr` because it was possible - and it makes it possible to use `static_assert`s.

Comment: @felixh _"need `reader.read<std::tuple<int, float>>()`"_ - Ok, can you add an example (one more call + assert) to the question to show how it'll be used?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's because you do it inside class declaration. But it works outside: https://godbolt.org/z/6vvY3eMoj

Comment: @felixh Ok, I added what I think can be used to solve that too.

Comment: @sklott Yes, but that's not needed with `requires`, which I find nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments made by @HolyBlackCat and @Jarod42, `T(read<U>(), ...)` should be `T{ read<U>() ... }`.

```cpp
    template<typename ...U>
    std::tuple<U...> read_impl(std::tuple<U...>* arg) {
        using T = std::tuple<U...>;
        return T{ read<U>() ... };
    }
```

I was reading fold expression feature (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and now I've learnt that "fold/reduce" is not same as "expanding".

Comment: You don't even need `T` there. Just `return {read<U>() ...};`